# How to hide columns in JTable so that they can be  accessed using tableModel.getValueAt(row,colHidden)?

Tags: java, jtable

How to hide columns in JTable so that they can still be accessed using `tableModel.getValueAt(row,colHidden)`?

I did that way, but then I was unable to access 6th column using `tableModel.getValueAt(row,6)`:

```
tbl.getColumnModel().getColumn(6).setPreferredWidth(0);
tbl.getColumnModel().getColumn(6).setMinWidth(0);
tbl.getColumnModel().getColumn(6).setMaxWidth(0);
```

Error message is:

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 6
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RecvCallsTable.getColumnModel().removeColumn(RecvCallsTable.getColumnModel().getColumn(5));
```

This will remove the column from the model, i.e, from the user's view but still be accessible using the index value. I use this all the time and it works perfectly

Answer (score 0):

You can call [`JTable#removeColumn`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#removeColumn%28javax.swing.table.TableColumn%29) to remove the column from the `JTable`, while it is still accessible through the model. This is better then setting the preferred width

But even with your method calls you should be able to access that data. Are you certain your table has 7 columns (since the first column is located at index 0, ...)

Comment: Yes, I know the first column starts with 0. It works if I don´t use tbl.getColumnModel().getColumn(6).setPreferredWidth(0);
 Therefore I wondered if there is any other method.